# javaFX LoadException

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

For a project I need to create a GUI using javaFX, so with a tutorial of scenebuiler/javaFX that I followed very closely I created a very basic GUI. But the load doesn't seem to work and throws an LoadException. I've seem a few similar problems online, but none of their answers seemed to fix mine. I have done as much googleFoo as I can trying similar guides and tutorials, but it just wont load.

I've tried Parent instead of AnchorPane, getClass instead of Main.class and more variations on the loader, I found online.

```js
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            System.out.println("pre load");
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/testView.fxml"));
            System.out.println("post load");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And the exception

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Dropbox/Technische%20informatica/OOP/EclipseWorkspace/javaFXtest/bin/application/testView.fxml:8

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/14158153.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/30452001.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/25437038.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/27229737.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/15096457.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyTestController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: The reason is quite clear: `ClassNotFoundException: MyTestController`. Does this class exist? Is the package correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it complains about the missing controller is the  MyTestController really not in a package eg application.MyTestController?

Comment: The tutorial showed me I needed to make a new package "controller", were MyTestController is in. But I'm pretty sure I also tried to just create the controller in "application". Ill just try to do this again. edit: controller in same package as main/fxml still gives the LoadException and Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyTestController

Comment: It works! None of the tutorials specified the controller with a package, so giving the fxml the controller application.MyTestController made it work